# DOS style input in a HTML from

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I want to simulate he old habit of a DOS programm input in a HTML from.
Think of it as an order form.
First I have bunch of form fields for entering names, addresses and so on.

After that I have several product groups.
Each group has only two fields. One for the product and another for the quantity.
Now, tabbing through the form I want to have a NEW set of two input fields for the specific group if the product field its NOT empty.
If you enter a product, you get the chance to enter another one. Entering non, you quickly tab yourself in the next group.

Now I'm thinking about and searching for the most efficient solution that offers the fastest way of entering data without using the mouse when inside this form.
I'm totally free using jquery, html5 or whatever. But I definitely want this way of input, that Turbo Pascal gave to me with a little loop and some ReadLn commands.

All suggestions are welcome

--edit

started coding:
Basic form will look like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testform for a DOS-like behavior</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>
<form action="testform.php" method="post" id="formmail">
    <fieldset id="person">
        <legend>Person</legend>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
        <br>
        <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
        <br>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="productgroup1">
        <legend>Product Group 1</legend>
        Product: <input type="text" name="product[1][]">
        Qty: <input type="text" name="qty[1][]">
    </fieldset>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*** Update

Discovering the powers of fiddle I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/zarquon42/HcbfH/

And it is basically what I want. That surprises me. Now I'm going to take a look if it works also in the context with several groups of input fields.

*** Next Update

Much shorter with some jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/zarquon42/NdD7v/

Comment: What have your tried? Post your code.

Comment: Write a regular webpage and open it using lynx - DOS-like experience guaranteed :D

Comment: You want a Shell Like ? See the [mongoDb example](http://www.mongodb.org/#) click on try it out. I'll use nodeJs or something like that to make it work ;).

Comment: Using lynx is a nice idea. But will give me some other disadvantages :-)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you could use the JQuery terminal emulator plugin?

http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a shell. I want to simulate the input behavior of a DOS programm (written in Turbo Pascal about ... at least 15 years ago) cause it's much faster in this case. Just tabbing from one field to the next, no mouse needed. Getting more fields if needed.